# What is Method Class Object in Ruby ? What does it do ? Why it cannot be instantiated?

Tags: ruby, class, lambda, block

By executing the following code it returns 'Method' which is a indicative of Method class object What is it ? What does it do ? Why it cannot be instantiated ? It does not have a new.
Also how can we add a `new` method as a constructor to Method class object ?

```
proc_obj = -> {puts "Hello Lambda"}

def pass_lambda proc
  puts "Begin"
  proc.yield
  puts "End"
end

pass_lambda proc_obj

puts proc_obj.method(:call).class
```

Answer (score 0):

`Method` is the class of all methods you can extract from a `Module`. If you want to define methods dynamically, use `define_method`, as methods can't be defined unbound (even though there is `UnboundMethod`. What you're looking for is `Proc.new` to define an anonymous method. If you want to bind that method, you can use `define_method(:method_name, &proc_you_defined)`.